# Sorting a list if internal list is empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have a list inside of another list. I need to add to the list only those elements whose internal list is not empty. The data is pulled from the server. The code contains 4 lists, Each inside of another - Companies - Shops - Campaigns - Coupons. I need to check if the Coupons list is not empty and add the elements related to that. I would be very thankfull if someone could help with that.

```
foreach (var row in Companies)
        {
            reportData.companies.Add(new Companies { ID = row.Id, name = row.BrandName });


            var Shops = logicService.CompanyShopService.GetShopsByCompany(row.Id);
            var Campaigns = logicService.CampaignService.GetCampaignsByCompany(row.Id);

            foreach (var shop in Shops)
            {
                reportData.companies.Where(item => item.ID == shop.ClientID).FirstOrDefault().shops.Add(new Distribution_Shops { Id = shop.Id, Name = shop.Name });
                var shop_campaigns = Campaigns.Where(item => item.ShopID == shop.Id);
                foreach (var campaign in shop_campaigns)
                {
                    var coupons = logicService.CouponsService.GetAllByCampaign(campaign.Id, false);

                    foreach (var company in reportData.companies)
                    {
                        foreach (var tmp_shop in company.shops)
                        {
                            
                            if (tmp_shop.Id == shop.Id)
                            {
                                tmp_shop.campaigns.Add(new Distribution_Campaign { Id = campaign.Id, Name = campaign.CampaignName, coupons = coupons});
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to test for an empty coupons list (I assume the type is something like `IEnumerable<Coupon>`)? Can the list be `null`? Try `if(coupons is not null && coupons.Any())`'

Comment: Yes, you are right. Its not a problem to check if the list is empty. But it is that i dont understand how to add elements to the other lists after i checked its actually not empty. Thanks for trying to help btw.